# Menu sliding after your mouse

Tags: javascript, menu, slide

I want to make something like this:

http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php

can you hover the menu? it's sliding some shadow on hover, how do I do this? is that JS? if yes, is there a tutorial for it? or is it possible to make it with CSS3?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the plugin: [jQuery lavalamp](http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/).

I'm think this can't be achieved only with CSS. You can use css3 and some transitions but i think it would require at least some minimal javascript.

Comment: Ah I see, this one is a bit difficult, is there another plugin for that?

Comment: @Jony well, i guess there are several plugins that achieve the same. Just give it a try, it is pretty well explained.